# Dart - List first element cannot be null?

Tags: dart

In VSCode, if I write

```
class foo {
    List<MyObj> some_objs = [];

    MyObj get firstObject { return some_objs[0] ?? MyObj() };    // Left operand can't be null?
}
```

Intellisense tells me the left side of this expression can't be null. Is this an Intellisense error? The list exists but nothing is added to it. New at Dart here, thanks for any help.

Comment: Correct.  If the list is empty, you will get a thrown exception, and never make it to MyObj(), or you will get one of the MyObj objects, which are apparently non-nullable.  So the IDE is correct.  Maybe your understanding of what happens on an empty list is not?

Comment: This is explained by the [`List.first`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/first.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, now I see. The *existence* of the first element isn't the same as whether it contains null.